# SQL Query performance tuning - Execution plan attached

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Have an query that runs long time. How to improve the query performance?

[image]

```
       DECLARE @p__linq__0 bigint = 131074
       ,@p__linq__1 datetimeoffset(7) = '2017-10-26 00:00:00 +00:00'
       ,@p__linq__2 datetimeoffset(7) = '2016-10-26 00:00:00 +00:00'
SELECT  distinct
            1 AS [C1],        
            [Extent5].[DisplayText] + ' (' + [Extent4].[ParameterCode] + ')' AS [C2],
            [Extent4].[ParameterCode] AS [ParameterCode], 
            [Extent5].[ParameterId] AS [ParameterId] 

--[Extent2].[ReceptionDate] AS [ReceptionDate], [Extent4].[ParameterId] AS [ParameterId], [Extent4].[ParameterCode] AS [ParameterCode]
                FROM    [dbo].[ClientSamples] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[SamplesView] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[SampleId] = [Extent2].[SampleId] 
                and [Extent1].[AccountCode] IN ('A00052498', 'A00091603', 'AFR000790', 'AFR025580', 'AFR033702', 'AFR034669', 'AFR065301')  
                AND [Extent2].[ReceptionDate] >= @p__linq__2 AND [Extent2].[ReceptionDate] <= @p__linq__1 
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[SampleTestFractionsView] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[SampleId] = [Extent3].[SampleId]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[ValidatedResults] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[SampleTestFractionId] = [Extent4].[SampleTestFractionId]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[ParameterTranslationsView] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[ParameterId] = [Extent5].[ParameterId] AND (@p__linq__0 = [Extent5].[LanguageId])
                WHERE ([Extent5].[DisplayText] + ' (' + [Extent4].[ParameterCode] + ')' IS NOT NULL OR 
                (CAST(LEN([Extent5].[DisplayText] + ' (' + [Extent4].[ParameterCode] + ')') AS int)) != 0) 
                AND ' ' <> ([Extent5].[DisplayText] + ' (' + [Extent4].[ParameterCode] + ')')
```

The query takes around 22 minutes to return the results and results count is : 1068 records. Here, the huge data is in below tables and record count also given

SampleTestFractionsView--14861227
ValidatedResults--74649333

Comment: can you post the query aswell?

Comment: Instead of a picture of the execution plan which shows basically nothing can you post the actual plan? Here is a great way to do that. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Remove the `distinct` unless it's absolutely necessary is about all we can tell you without the query and plan via @SeanLange link.

Comment: Also, define "long time", and provide information about how many records the query is dealing with.  One person's "long time" might be another person's "wow - that was quick!"

Comment: Without seeing what's the view definitions, it's just guessing. Also, views behave you badly sometimes, you should try how it works without them too.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without the knowledge about the count(*) in each joined branch.
But in general:

- remove the `distinct` and see how many records **actually** feet your conditions
- if selection from "small" tables with and without distinct differs dramatically, try to distinct it before joining the "huge" part [read this article for the examples](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/4-ways-to-join-only-the-first-row-in-sql)
- try to remove inline function calls in your `WHERE` section (you can temporary remove it at all)